# How to store the image in mysql database from android using webservice and axis2?

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services

I have created a signup page in android, which contains some text boxes for names and an  upload button (which I used to get Images from gallery) and have to store it in mysql.

I have googled it and I got some codes they are using php but I'm not using php.
Please provide some useful links or codes.
How can I store image into mysql using web services?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public void insertImg(int id , Bitmap img ) {   


    byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function

    insertStatement_logo.bindLong(1, id);       
    insertStatement_logo.bindBlob(2, data);

    insertStatement_logo.executeInsert();
    insertStatement_logo.clearBindings() ;

}

 public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

And to retrieve:

```
  public Bitmap getImage(int i){

    String qu = "select img  from table where feedid=" + i ;
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(qu, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()){
        byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);
        cur.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
    }
    if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
        cur.close();
    }       

    return null ;
}
```

Comment: @Mallikarjun Hampannavar have you used it?

Comment: K where I have to use these methods? I have one web servise class and activity class(android). Once I upload image from gallery then I have to store that image into mysql database through web servise. Please clerify

Comment: You can use these methods after you successfully uploaded the image to the webservice.

Comment: Ok sir thanku.. I'll use it and let you know the result.. Thanks